# Remove id field

Tags: pyspark, databricks

Remove id field from the nested array of json object having key values pairs (empval) using pyspark

**Input**

```
+----------+--------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| empno    | empcode| empval                                                                                                   |
+----------+--------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| employee1| 100DRE | [{"id": "123", "key1": "aeroplane", "key2": "bus", "key3": "null", key4: "null"}, {"id": "234", "key1": "te", "key2": "buses", "key3": "token", key4: "null"}, {"id": "345", "key1": "grtregert", "key2": "buggy", "key3": "", key4: "null"}] |
+----------+--------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

**Expected output**

```
+----------+--------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| empno    | empcode| newColumn                                                                                                           |
+----------+--------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| employee1| 100DRE | [ "key1": "aeroplane", "key2": "bus", "key3": "null", key4: "null"}, { "key1": "te", "key2": "buses", "key3": "token", key4: "null"},  "key1": "grtregert", "key2": "buggy", "key3": "", key4: "null"}]|
+----------+--------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

```
df
.selectExpr(
   "empno", 
   "empcode", 
   "to_json(from_json(empval, 'array<struct<key1: string, key2: string, key3: string, key4: string>>')) AS newColumn"
)
```

Comment: You already have the answer in your question... What's the question?!

Comment: what's your question ?? here ..

Comment: Input is
[{"id": "value1", "key1": null, "key2": "value2", "key3": "value3", "key4": "value4"}, {"id": "value1", "key1": null, "key2": null, "key3": "value3", "key4": "value4"}

Expected output

Comment: If for example key1 is not inputted, then it should return as key1: null rather than just displaying the rest of the fields with the values.

Comment: It is expected.. spark will not display or store if any of the attribute value is null.